# Can I ask a professor (via e-mail) for a citation for a result presented in lecture notes?

Tags: professorship, etiquette

A mathematical result is presented in a set of lecture notes by a professor, and I have not been able to locate any journal papers which include the result. Would it be appropriate to ask the professor, via e-mail, for a citation to a journal paper?

---

Note: I am not a student of the lecturer.

Comment: I assume you have thought long and hard about the statement and are reasonably sure that it is not a consequence of the preceding results in the lecture notes, yes? Sometimes such statements are left in textbooks and notes as exercises for the attentive reader, and not always are such exercises marked as such.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: Yes, the result isn't derived, though it is stated how to derive it. The lecture notes don't have a bibliography, nor are there any on the course website, or even the prof's personal site. I also checked textbooks which I knew the professor used for the notes, but have not found it.

Comment: The answers notwithstanding, an alternative: take your question to the appropriate SE site, probably [physics.SE]?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, it can't hurt to send a brief, polite email. Just make **sure** that the reference isn't already given somewhere in the notes, or the professor's course website, or his/her list of suggested reading.

Of course, you should prepare for the possibility that your email will go unanswered. Professors tend to be busy. There is little-to-no benefit to them (other than the pleasure of helping out another human being, that is) in tracking down a reference for someone who isn't a colleague, student, or potential collaborator. There's also the possibility that this professor didn't prepare his/her own lecture notes, and the grad student who *did* is long gone, etc.

Comment: E-mail sent! I'll let you know of the outcome :)

Comment: He replied within minutes with an answer; thanks!

Comment: @user1997744 Put him on your list of prospective supervisors!

Comment: @Moriarty: I'm 16 years old, doing self-study, but sure :) The result was a metric tensor which was a solution to the low energy equations of motion of a string theory, and I couldn't find it anywhere else.

Comment: @user1997744 That's very impressive!